# How to stop rails from adding BUNDLED WITH to the Gemfile.lock

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm working with a distributed team of developers and I'm getting this issue of having to commit the Gemfile.lock with bundled with info added to the bottom:

`BUNDLED WITH
   1.10.2`

We're obviously using different versions of things, ie rvm/rbenv, and I'm wondering if there's a way to stop my system doing this.

Bundler version 1.10.2 (obviously)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After digging around a bit, and looking through those issues and comments shared by Jorge, you really only have two options:

1. Downgrade your version of bundler to something earlier than 1.10
2. Ask your whole team to update their versions of bundler to something later than 1.10

   gem uninstall bundler

   gem install bundler -v 1.9.9

But as long as the downgrade doesn't cause any issues, it should be fine.

The developers for the bundler gem are not going to make any changes to the gem that will eliminate this problem.  They're reasoning is that eventually everyone will be upgraded to something after 1.10.

Answer (score 6):

Locate the file `lib/bundler/definition.rb` in your local installation of the bundler gem (you can use `gem env` to locate the folder where your gems are installed) and remove these three lines

```
  # Record the version of Bundler that was used to create the lockfile
  out << "\nBUNDLED WITH\n"
  out << "   #{lock_version}\n"
```

You might need to restart spring after the change

Comment: While this will technically work, it's generally a bad idea to edit your gem's source code to force it to work this way.